# Regex to get unique values in field using QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, regular-expression

I need to get the unique values from a field.

```
(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)
```

Works in an [online test](https://regex101.com/r/AeTqCE/1) but I get invalid expression in QGIS Field Calculator. How can I rewrite this in QGIS Regex implementation or is there another maybe pythonic way to get the same result? In the end it needs to work in QGIS Modeller.

```
regexp_matches( "Locality_L","(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)")
```

[image]

**Update 2**
As per @she_weeds suggestion I tried with '' around the regex statement, it runs but there's no value in the table even though a sample result is shown in the field calc pane.
[image]

Comment: The second parameter in regexp_matches (the actual regex) is a string literal and therefore requires single quote marks (`'`), not double quotes (`"`) which is interpreted as a column reference (hence the error)

Comment: @she_weeds it runs now but no values are shown in the table. See updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using regex_match you can define a new function and use that custom function to extract the unique text without using regular expression.

You can use the following function to do the job:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def unique_text(text_field, feature, parent):
    split_text = text_field.split(',')
    lower = [txt.lower().strip() for txt in split_text]
    uniqueText = set(lower)
    joinUnique = (",".join(uniqueText)).title()
    return joinUnique
```

Using `Field Calculator ->` go to `Function Editor` and create a new expression and give it a name, in this example `ExtractUniqueText`

[image]

Under the `Field Calculator -> Custom` use Unique_text which is the name of the defined function with the field name that you want to extract the unique text from.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Custom function works well. unfortunately array_distinct() function in QGIS works only on numbers, otherwise that would have been an ideal solution.

Comment: @spatialthoughts I agree with you. `array_distinct()` would be excellent if it works with text also.

Answer (score 3):

Because you used `regexp_matches()` instead of `regexp_match()` it will return an array (notice the square brackets in Output preview at the bottom of your field calc screenshot) as opposed to a string. You need to convert the array to a string by wrapping your expression in `array_to_string()`.

You also need to escape any backslashes so `\1` needs to be `\\1`.

It appears that there some further tweaks you will need to make to your regex; different dialects behave differently - I would recommend testing against the Python flavour.